# Show that $\lambda_{max} \left(H+(h\otimes h)H^{-1}\right)=\left\|H+\sqrt{h}\otimes\sqrt{h}\right\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Suppose $h=(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$, $\sqrt{h}=(\sqrt{h_1},\ldots,\sqrt{h_n})$, $H=\text{diag}(h)$, $a\otimes a=aa'$.

What is the easiest way to show the following for operator norm $\|.\|$ and largest eigenvalue $\lambda_\text{max}$?

$$\lambda_{max} \left(H+0.5(h\otimes h)H^{-1}\right)=\left\|H+0.5\sqrt{h}\otimes\sqrt{h}\right\|$$

Motivation: reciprocal of this [gives](http://yaroslavvb.com/convergence.pdf) the largest learning which guarantees convergence of LMS when observations come from zero-centered Gaussian with diagonal covariance matrix and entries $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $H + 0.5(h \otimes h)H^{-1}$ is similar to
$$
H^{-1/2}(H + 0.5(h \otimes h)H^{-1})H^{1/2} = \\
H^{-1/2}HH^{1/2} + 0.5H^{-1/2}h h' H^{-1}H^{1/2} = \\
H + 0.5H^{-1/2}h h' H^{-1/2}=\\
H + 0.5(H^{-1/2}h)(H^{-1/2}h)' =\\
H + 0.5\sqrt{h} \otimes \sqrt{h}.
$$
Thus, we have $\lambda_{\max}(H + 0.5(h \otimes h)H^{-1}) = \lambda_{\max}(H + 0.5\sqrt{h} \otimes \sqrt{h})$. However, $H + 0.5\sqrt{h} \otimes \sqrt{h}$ is symmetric, which means that $\lambda_{\max}(H + 0.5\sqrt{h} \otimes \sqrt{h}) = \|H + 0.5\sqrt{h} \otimes \sqrt{h}\|$.

Comment: Between line 2 and 3, your leftmost 1/2 became -1/2, how is that justified?

Comment: Did you mean the right-most? If so, $H^{-1}H^{1/2}=H^{-1/2}$.